# Proguard returned with error code 127. See console

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm trying to export my android project (Export Unsigned Application Package) but getting the following error:

> Proguard returned with error code 127. See console
>
> /path/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/proguard/bin/proguard.sh: 9: java:
> not found

I'm running eclipse on ubuntu. any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there proguard.sh file in that folder?

Comment: yes, there is . I just put there the whole path to java. but now I'm getting another error /opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/proguard/bin/proguard.sh: 9: /opt/jdk1.6.0_21/bin: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also get this problem,and the error is than system can not find 'java' command,so just export your java path or in proguard.sh Replace 'java' with your java command's full path.

Comment: thanks, I've done it already, just forgot to add the answer:) I'll mark yours as the answer.